# Toggle only working the first time

Tags: jquery

I wrote this Jquery script to toggle a popup, now everything is working fine except for the part that the toggle is only working 1 time.

I saw it has something to do with the event bubbling initially and i need to do something with .stopPropagation(), only I'm not getting it fixed

```
$(function() {
    $(".nonrefundable a").on("click", function(e) {
        var link = this;

        e.preventDefault();
        $( "#popup" ).toggle();
        $("#ok").click(function () {
                    window.location = link.href;

        });
        $("#nope").click(function () {
            $( "#popup" ).toggle(); 

        });

    });
});
```

working code http://jsfiddle.net/Td42s/

Comment: Each time you click on a link, you add two event handlers ("#ok" and "#nope"). You should move these out of the click handler.

Comment: ... I should have written this in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : You are biniding `click` event to `ok` and `nope` when every time you click `nonrefundatable` anchor, just bind it once and change value of `link` variable inside click function of anchor.

**Note** : always put `e.preventDefault()` at the start of function

```
$(function() {
    var link ;
    $(".nonrefundable a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        link = this;
        $( "#popup" ).toggle();       
    });

    $("#ok").click(function () {
         window.location = link.href;        
    });

    $("#nope").click(function () {
        $( "#popup" ).toggle(); 
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Td42s/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEM**

You are putting your `#nope` and `#ok` click handler in wrong place.

This will assign handlers in each time you click anchor.

**SOLUTION**

So, you need to assign `click` handlers outside.

Do this:

```
$(function() {
    var link;
    $(".nonrefundable a").on("click", function(e) {
        link = this;
        $( "#popup" ).toggle();

    });
    $("#ok").click(function () {
        window.location = link.href;

    });
    $("#nope").click(function () {
        $( "#popup" ).toggle(); 

    });
});
```

Take a look at how it works:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Td42s/5/)**

Comment: you have define var link inside click of anchor and using it in ok button click. define it globaly.

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace Your Js Code with This Code

```
$(function() {
    $(".nonrefundable a").on("click", function(e) {
        var link = this;

        e.preventDefault();
        $( "#popup" ).toggle();
        $("#ok").click(function () {
                    window.location = link.href;

        });
        $("#nope").unbind('click').click(function () {
           $( "#popup" ).toggle(); 

        });

    });
});
```

Hope this would help you

Comment: What about unbinding `#ok` click handler?

Comment: you are taking $("#nope").click(function() inside $(".nonrefundable a").on("click", function(e) so when you are clicking on nope it was clicking two time which was showing you a closing #popup and you were pretending toggle is working only once

Comment: I mean you unbind `#nope` click handler before adding new one (which doesn't look like good idea in whole, but at least doesn't produce multiple hanging handlers), but you somewhy haven't done the same for `#ok`

Comment: yes you can use unbind same for okay as well,i forgot to mention that or you can simple use #ok and #nope code outside      $(".nonrefundable a").on("click", function(e) function without using unbind